# How do use REST API in Marketo to add leads as members into Programs?

Tags: marketo

How do you use REST API in Marketo to add leads as members into programs?

I have created folders, programs and leads using REST API.

Now I want to add specific leads by using their ID into Programs as members.

How do I do it using REST API or do I need to use a different method?

Please let me know.

Comment: Formatting and typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Change Lead Program Status" End point: http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/changeLeadProgramStatusUsingPOST

Example call: 
POST `/rest/v1/leads/programs/{programId}/status.json`

```
data={
    "status": "Registered",
    "input": [
        {"id": 123}
    ]
}
```

So you can add up to 300 Lead IDs, but only 1 status at a time (for 1 Program).

Comment: Wow it helped a lot.

Comment: Is there any option in REST or SOAP to add new Campaign, instead of Program?

Comment: i am using GetLeadsByProgramID to get the Leads with Status under a Program. But is there any way where i can get status of only 1 lead for a program?

Comment: i got the answer,...sharing the link with you 
                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169450/how-do-use-rest-api-in-marketo-to-add-leads-as-members-into-programs